# Mass assignment for has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models: `User` and `Item`. These models have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between them (i.e. there is a 'pivot table' that associates multiple users with multiple items).

Typically, when a user is created, items are associated with it (but new items are not created). When creating a new user (via mass-assignment) how can I also assign to it certain items?

For example, if my controller receives the following params hash:

```
params = {
  user: {
    email: 'someone@example.com',
    item_ids: [1,2,3]
  }
}

user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:email, :item_ids))
```

How can I make sure items with IDs 1,2,3 get associated with the newly created user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to whitelist `item_ids` as an array param:

```
user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:email, {item_ids: []}))
```